# Dictionary comprehension produce different result from loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The loop to check whether hand contain letter in word work as below.

```
hand = {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
word = 'hello'

extra_hand = hand.copy()

for letter in word: 
    extra_hand[letter] -= 1

>> extra_hand
{'h': 0, 'e': 0, 'l': 0, 'o': 0}
```

Then, I try to convert to Dictionary comprehension. It should look like this.

```
hand = {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
word = 'hello'
extra_hand = {letter:hand[letter] - 1 for letter in word}

>>extra_hand
{'h': 0, 'e': 0, 'l': 1, 'o': 0}
```

As you can see, the result is different, l is 1 which incorrect. I suspect that 'l' were derived from hand dictionary object without mutation. So, it just did 2-1 twice and become 1 rather than 2-1 and 1-1.

What should I do to fix the dictionary comprehension please?

Comment: Well, the reason is pretty obvious: in the first scenario for the letter `l` you subtract `1` twice, as you're manipulating inplace. In the second example you don't manipulate inplace, `hand[letter]` is still 2. Hence you also get `1` when reading a second `l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension cannot be used in this recursive manner. It cannot continually update an item as `word` is iterated.

Another way to think of this is that the keys and values of your dictionary are not available for manipulation until the entire comprehension is complete.

You can consider the dictionary comprehension to be replicating the `for` loop below. As with the `for` loop, you will be setting values rather than adding to the value previously assigned to the key.

```
for letter in word:
    extra_hand['letter'] = hand['letter'] - 1
```

Your loop is perfectly fine and there is no need to use a dictionary comprehension.

---

As an alternative, if you only wish to calculate non-zero counts, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

hand = {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
word = 'hello'
res = Counter(hand) - Counter(word)

# Counter()

hand = {'h': 1, 'e': 2, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
word = 'hello'
res = Counter(hand) - Counter(word)

# Counter({'e': 1})
```

Comment: Counter is very handy here!

Comment: Thank you so much. The key take away is I should use loop for dictionary in this case. I also learn new thing about Counter, too. Thanks for your sharing.  :D

Answer (score 1):

Your both methods do not mean the same. If the dictionary comprehension method would be tranlated in loops, you would get

```
hand = {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
word = 'hello'
extra_hand = {}
for letter in word:
    extra_hand[letter] = hand[letter] - 1
```

So, `hand['l']` is never changed and therefore, it's still `2` when the loop reaches the second `l`. That's why you get the value `1` both times.

In my opinion, the loop variant is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
extra_hand = {letter:hand[letter] - 1 for letter in word}
```

is equivalent to:

```
for letter in word: 
    extra_hand[letter] = hand[letter] - 1
```

And not:

```
for letter in word: 
    extra_hand[letter] -= 1
```

In the first case, `extra_hand['l']` equals to `1`, while in the second case, you subtract 1 twice (which gives `0`).